# C# says Font was forwarded to System.Drawing.Common but then says that doesn't exist?

Tags: c#

I'm created a C# project for a .cs file that I downloaded.   The project says .Net 7.0 is the target.  It complains that `Font` has been moved to `System.Drawing.Common`.  Then you try to use that and it says it doesn't exist.

Error first build attempt:

```
error CS1069: The type name 'Font' could not be found in the namespace 'System.Drawing'. This type has been forwarded to assembly 'System.Drawing.Common, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' Consider adding a reference to that assembly.
```

Error after adding `using System.Drawing.Common;`

```
error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Common' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Drawing' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
error CS1069: The type name 'Font' could not be found in the namespace 'System.Drawing'. This type has been forwarded to assembly 'System.Drawing.Common, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' Consider adding a reference to that assembly.
```

I don't get it?  What am I supposed to use? Am I missing an assembly reference?  What is an assembly reference and where do you add them?

TIA!!

Comment: It is the name of an assembly, not of a namespace.  Don't change the code, only [add the assembly](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Drawing.Common/7.0.0).

Comment: It depends, if you're using Visual Studio, check out this link: [Add a reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-add-or-remove-references-by-using-the-reference-manager?view=vs-2022#add-a-reference).